# Is VAPID keys are unique to each server for web push notifications?

Tags: django, push-notification, vapid

While implementing push notification (in Django framework), I have used VAPID keys which generated by a website (https://vapidkeys.com/).

Can I use any random dummy text for these keys instead of generating using any other platforms ?

Or does these VAPID keys being checked with any server during push notification process ?